# What is the smell from growing beer yeast and is there any adverse effects from the odor/fumes

Tags: yeast

What are the fumes from growing beer yeast and is there any adverse toxic problems?

Comment: DO you mean yeast growing in a starter? Or do you mean yeast fermenting a batch in a bucket or carboy?  It doesn't matter but I am curious.

Answer (score 3):

You are smelling esters, aldehydes and sulfides at different levels.  There are a host of many other compounds that might be coming out too.

It is not harmful.

Comment: Also, uh, CO2. :)

Comment: CO2 doesn't have an aroma really.  It'll burn your nostrils if you get a good face full of it, but otherwise its odorless.

Comment: @brewchez mentioned sulfides. They can smell like rotten eggs. They are prominent in lager brewing and be a big surprise when you open your fermentation chamber/cupboard and that smell attacks you! :) Remember, if you can smell it then in is no longer in your beer.